# Wrapping each line inside quotation marks with AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have two thousand lines of text. I need each line to be wrapped inside quotation marks like "example".

**Before**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

**After**

```
"line 1"
"line 2"
"line 3"
```

How could I take care of this with AutoHotkey?

Comment: Where are those lines of text? Is it in a flat .txt file? Is each line terminated by a NewLine/CarriageReturn? Is it something you only need to do once? My first thought would be to just use Find/Replace and replace the EndOfLine (e.g. the LibreOffice Find/Replace uses all the unix like regex with $ etc.) to replace the EOL+NL/CR with "EOL+NL/CR". Now you only need to correct the first line (add the " at the beginning) and the last line...

Comment: Inside AutoHotKey, I would read the lines in with a [loop, read, xxx.txt] command, add the "s and write the modified lines to a new xxx.txt file. But if you only need this once, I would opt for edit/replace.

Comment: B.t.w. the much more lightweight PSPad does offer find/replace with regex as well. Just replace ^ with " and $ with " in Search/Replace with the Regular Expressions flag turned on. B.t.w., still have not seen your reply about this being a once-off event or something that justifies writing a small script.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
text=
(
bla bla bla
blah blah blah blah
blablah blablah blablah
)
MsgBox %    RegExReplace(RegExReplace(text,"`am)^.","""$0"),"`am).$","$0""")
```